# Find percent difference between row below and row above in R and create new column

Tags: r

I want to find the percent difference between the row below and the row above and put the difference into a new column. My data frame (df) looks like this

```
Date_Time               WC_30cm_neg
2018-01-01 05:50:01     0.3051
2018-01-01 06:00:01     0.3048
2018-01-01 06:10:01     0.3048
2018-01-01 06:20:01     0.3048
2018-01-01 06:30:01     0.3051
2018-01-01 06:40:01     0.3051
```

I've tried:

```
df_diff <- df %>% 
 arrange(Date_Time) %>% 
 group_by(WC_30cm_neg) %>% 
 mutate(
  diff=WC_30cm_neg-lag(WC_30cm_neg),
 increase=scales::percent(diff / lag(WC_30cm_neg))
 ) %>%
 filter(row_number()!=1)
```

This returns me a new data frame, and gives me a percent column, but all of the percentages are 0. Any other suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you wrote `group_by(WC_30cm_neg)`, so you are grouping by a single number and then subtracting that same number. By definition, all differences have to be zero. Do you mean to group by a different variable?

Comment: I deleted that part of the code, and now it runs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to just remove the `group_by()`?

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Date_Time,              ~WC_30cm_neg,
  "2018-01-01 05:50:01",    0.3051,
  "2018-01-01 06:00:01",    0.3048,
  "2018-01-01 06:10:01",    0.3048,
  "2018-01-01 06:20:01",    0.3048,
  "2018-01-01 06:30:01",    0.3051,
  "2018-01-01 06:40:01",    0.3051
)

df |>
  mutate(
    diff = WC_30cm_neg - lag(WC_30cm_neg),
    increase = scales::percent(diff / lag(WC_30cm_neg))
  )
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   Date_Time           WC_30cm_neg      diff increase
#>   <chr>                     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 2018-01-01 05:50:01       0.305 NA        <NA>    
#> 2 2018-01-01 06:00:01       0.305 -0.000300 -0.098% 
#> 3 2018-01-01 06:10:01       0.305  0        0.000%  
#> 4 2018-01-01 06:20:01       0.305  0        0.000%  
#> 5 2018-01-01 06:30:01       0.305  0.000300 0.098%  
#> 6 2018-01-01 06:40:01       0.305  0        0.000%
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>